# How to set up profile in spring boot to mock external api for development

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, spring-profiles

I'm trying to set up my spring boot application so that when I run:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

and then go to `localhost:9099/api/resources`, the code accesses the actual endpoint. Then, if I run

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Pmock
```

and go to `localhost:9099/api/resources`, the code returns a mocked list of resources.

Right now, if I exclude the `-Pmock` argument, I can access the actual endpoint just fine, but if I include the `-Pmock` argument, I get a 404. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Here is what I have implemented:

pom.xml

```
...
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>macos-m1</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>mac</family>
                    <arch>aarch64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    // mac m1 specific dependency - needed on dev machine only
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>mock</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>mock</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile> -->
    </profiles>
...
```

ResourceController.java

```
@RestController
@Profile("!mock")
public final class ResourceController {

    @GetMapping("/api/resources")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Resource>> getAll() {
        List<Resource> payload = // call service to get all resources
        return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(payload);
    }
}
```

ResourceControllerMock.java

```
@RestController
@Profile("mock")
public final class ResourceController {

    @GetMapping("/api/resources")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Resource>> getAll() {
        List<Resource> payload = List.of(new Resource(x,y,z));
        return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(payload);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have application-mock.properties file on classpath?

Comment: No, I don't.  I didn't think I needed it because I'm not setting any properties specific to the mock profile.

Comment: You could have one with this line: spring.profiles.active=mock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the command wrong to run a specific profile.

Use the below command and it should work fine

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=mock`

Also you don't need to write a `mock` profile section in the `pom.xml` file, if you use the above command.

Reference:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html